# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; not working on iOS cordova iPad app

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, webkit-overflow-scrolling

I'm using `cordova@9.0.0` with `iOS@5.1.1` with `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1` plugin.
Scrolling is working fine on all devices except iPad. I installed my app on [iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr2yl.png) (iOS 13.3), no problems. On [iPad 7th gen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEHEP.png) (iOS 13.3) it doesn't scroll and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is marked as not supported. Can anyone help?